# will ssh work with a .cer file?

Tags: ssh, certificate

I'm trying to set up an Avalance node on AWS.  When following the instructions to set up a key pair, the file generated was a `.cer` file instead of a `.pem` file.  Will I still be able to `SSH` onto the instance?

I'm on a mac and I'm not able to get the SSH to work.  I don't know, however, what the issue is.  It's not giving me an error.  It's just sitting there with no response.

Got the instructions here: https://docs.avax.network/build/tutorials/nodes-and-staking/setting-up-an-avalanche-node-with-amazon-web-services-aws/

Comment: What instructions did you follow? Please copy the relevant bit into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Convert a DER file (.crt .cer .der) to PEM

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
```

Comment: I ended up just changing the extention from .cer to .pem using finder in my Mac. Seems to work. Is that gonna compromise my security?